# Why I don't need to give the independent new table a name here?

Tags: mysql, select

This is raw data to create the two tables:

```
Create table Customers (Id int, Name varchar(255));

Create table Orders (Id int, CustomerId int);

insert into Customers (id,name) values
('1', 'Joe'),
('2', 'Henry'),
('3', 'Sam'),
('4', 'Max');

insert into Orders (Id, CustomerId) values
('1', '3'), ('2', '1');
```

And I would like to write a SQL query to find all customers who never order anything. This is my code:

```
select
name as customers
from
customers
where
customers.id 
not in 
(select
customerid
from
orders) as cus_id;
```

And SQL response is I shouldn't add "as cus_id" here. But shouldn't I give a new name to the new independent table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot and don't need to add an alias in this case. The subquery is local to the `NOT IN` operation and cannot be referenced anywhere else anyway.

Apart from that, what you could do is to use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`. `NOT EXISTS` can perform better especially when `orders` is large but there's an index on `orders (customerid)`.

```
SELECT c.name AS customers
       FROM customers AS c
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM orders AS  o
                                WHERE o.customerid = c.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

As "sticky bit" mentions, there's no need to add an alias to your subquery after `not in` because it cannot be referenced in other places.

Here is a different, but potentially simpler approach for returning customers who never order anything. By using a left join, all rows from the `Customers` table are returned. And by using `where o.CustomerId is null`, this returns all customers from the `Customers` table that have no orders in the `Orders` table.

```
select c.*
from Customers c 
left join Orders o on 
    c.id = o.CustomerId
where o.CustomerId is null
```

**Output**

```
Id  Name
2   Henry
4   Max
```

You can play around with the query [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t6bjuxKu2c8mgFGw6QZ8oo/1)